# How to remove "YEAR/MONTH/" from uploads URL & redirect old URL to the new form?

Tags: redirect, regex

I have disabled "Organize my uploads into month and year-based folders".

The links to my PDF files were of the form:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/document.pdf
```

And now they are:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/document.pdf
```

Is it possible to redirect all my `.../YEAR/MONTH/...` PDF URLs to the new URL without the `YEAR/MONTH/` part?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you'll be in trouble when there are multiple documents with the same name within different `/year/month/` directory.

Comment: I have delete them manually, so thats under control. Its more for pages that is indexed on Google & Bing.

Answer (score 1):

The .htaccess `RewriteRule` to rewrite only `.pdf` to not use /year/month/ can look like this

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+?)$ /wp-content/uploads/$3.pdf [L,R=301]
```

You should add this prior to WordPress' rules, so it will be evaluated before them, resulting in a .htaccess file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.+?)\.pdf$ /wp-content/uploads/$3.pdf [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Nice ! Its almost there.
It shall only be PDF files, not images and videos. 

Is that possible ?

Comment: @HPetersen I've updated the answer